# Merging different files with git

Tags: git, version-control

I'm not very experienced with git, but I have a situation I would like help with.

Working on my feature branch I have just realized I have been working on an obsolete file X, say. On master another file, Y, is used in X's place, while file X gathers dust (nobody deleted it).
I want to merge my branch into master and add my commits in file X put into file Y.

Is this possible?
I've been looking at **rebase** and other things but I'm not really sure what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work: while in your `feature` branch you could rename the useless `file_X` into `file_Y` (using `git mv`). Commit the changes while in the `feauture` branch.
Then you move on the `master` branch and you merge the `feauture` branch into the `master`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [`git mv`](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mv.html) is in order?

```
git mv X Y
git commit
```